# I can't install the library digi-xbee

Tags: xbee

I can't install the library 'digi-xbee' to my python 2.7.
When i run this command `pip install digi-xbee`, i had this error: No matching distribution found for digi-xbee

Could you help me for fixing this error ?

Comment: Python2 isn't supported anymore. You should use Python3.

Comment: Well, how can i check if python 3 is installed or not ?

Comment: Call `python3 --help`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the PyPi repo it's only available for Python 3

https://pypi.org/project/digi-xbee/

Comment: i installed python3 but the error "No matching distribution found for digi-xbee" persists.What must i do ?

Comment: For python 3 you need to use `pip3` instead of `pip`